# I am getting error trying to install tweepy using different approaches

Tags: python, installation, tweepy

I am using windows through Anaconda and my python version is :
3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

When I try to install tweepy I am getting the below error :

pip3 install tweepy
  File "", line 1
    pip3 install tweepy
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have tried these commands none of them worked

1-

```
 pip3 install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
File "<ipython-input-13-0fd3f62684d3>", line 1
    pip3 install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

2-

pip3 install tweepy
File "", line 1
pip3 install tweepy
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

3-

```
 pip install tweepy --ignore-installed six
```

4-

```
  pip install tweepy --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Even once I try to install it from anaconda , the tweepy is not available[image: anaconda]
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: You seem to be running those commands in a Python interpreter; they're for the command line.

Comment: I tried running it via cmd , although it is saying it was successful, python is giving me the same error